CORS Issue with Context-Path in Spring Boot Application
I'm having an issue with configuring CORS in my Spring Boot application. I've set a context-path for all exposed endpoints like this:
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: '/api'

Here is my CORS configuration:
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "web.cors")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private String allowedOrigins;
    private String allowedMethods;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins.split(","))
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}

Here is my application.yaml:

web:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: http://localhost:8080, http://localhost
    allowed-methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD

However, when my frontend (running on http://localhost:8080) tries to call GET /api/markets, I get a CORS-related error.
Interestingly, if I change .addMapping("/api/**") to .addMapping("/**") in my CORS configuration, it works fine.
Is there anything I am missing in my CORS configuration that affects the context-path?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I am guessing context-path doesn't get recognized as part of the route, therefore what the FilterChain processes is only the part after, being market. Therefore /** works and /api/** doesn't

pretty much ad @asgarov1 said, it seems like first the context allows any call to /api entrypoint, then the CORS configuration takes place inside with any /** route. So trying to have a .addMapping("/api/**") would work (redundantly) just for localhost:<PORT>/api/api/<RESOURCE>
